# GNOME on Ubuntu Server and Display Manager not configured

Tags: server, gnome, tasksel

I installed GNOME on Ubuntu Server 20.04 on a Dell T-320 using tasksel but did not do anything with the display manager. Now, when I startup the server, I get an unreadable GNOME startup with no where to go. The screen is full of squiggly lines. How do I correct this?? Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: GNOME desktop finally became "readable". Not sure how this occurred by itself.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post the Ubuntu release and hardware specifications.

Comment: It has occurred again and now the desktop is unreadable.

Comment: Your [Dell PowerEdge T320](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/ja-jp/poweredge-t320/t320ownersmanual/technical-specifications?guid=guid-e8bdfcc6-3ab0-4ca0-ae9b-d1c76a959dcc&lang=en-us) has a 16MB video card. The fact that GNOME could appear at all is amazing, as it generally demands far more. Servers are not intended to run UIs, so have very weak video systems. If you must use a UI, consider XFCE or something just as light 

Comment: Thanks @matigo, I was just playing around with it and honestly am fine with command line only.